# Trying to create a List of user-defined objects, getting NullPointerException

Tags: list

I'm working on an Android app. I created (in a separate .java file) an object like so:

```
class RRS_Location {
String tagname;
String href;

// Constructor
public RRS_Location(String tagname, String href) {
    this.tagname = tagname;
    this.href = href;
}

public String getTagname()  {
    return tagname;
}

public String getHref() {
    return href;
}
}
```

Within an activity, I've declared a List of these items
`List<RRS_Location> rrs_list;`

I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to add an RRS_Location object to the list. I'm doing so using this code
    `rrs_list.add(new RRS_Location(e1, e2));`

I've used Toast to echo back to me that I have valid Strings e1 and e2. Any ideas on why I'm getting the exception? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you instantiating `rrs_list` before making the call to `add`?

`List<RRS_Location> rrs_list = new ArrayList<RRS_Location>();`

If not, this is why you are getting a NullPointerException, you are attempting to invoke a method on a `null` object.

Comment: No I hadn't wasn't instantiating the list. But, when I add in the complete line that you show, it's telling me that `ArrayList<RRS_Location> can not be resolved to a type`. I'm not sure what that means...

Comment: You probably need to import the `java.util.ArrayList` package to make use of `ArrayList`. If you are using Eclipse, CTRL+SHIFT+O will organize your imports for the current class, adding needed imports and removing unused ones.

Comment: What about `RRS_Location`? Is that imported as well? Again, CTRL+SHIFT+O will handle the needed imports automatically.

Comment: Hhhmmm...I thought you had it there, but when I import `RRS_Location`, the error doesn't go away. Nor does it change...

Comment: Try clearing the Lint Markers then. Right click the Android project in the package explorer -> Android Tools -> Clear Lint Markers. Sometimes, these error marks get "stuck", even when the error has been corrected and you need to forcefully clear them. See http://images.frandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/AndroidAdt16Lint.png for example, last option.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting the `Clear Lint Markers` prompt. I posted a snapshot of my options at www.sinisterlabs.com/untitled.JPG , maybe that'll help?

Comment: I see the problem, you have `List<RRS_Location> rrs_list = new ArrayList<RSS_Location>();` it should be `List<RRS_Location> rrs_list = new ArrayList<RRS_Location>();`.

Comment: Look closer at the class names in the `<>` template brackets for `ArrayList` ;)